# При добавлении прав пользователю не могу подключиться

Tags: docker, ssh

Запускаю ASP.net проект в докере с ssh. Создаю еще одного пользователя(useradd user1), и все работает. Но когда добавляю пользователю права (useradd -ou 0 -g 0 user1). То не получается подключиться по ssh, пишет что нету разрешения по паролю. И не получается через root подключиться, пример docker:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 22

COPY . .
RUN echo 'root:qwe' | chpasswd
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN apt-get install -y mc
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd

RUN useradd -ou 0 -g 0 user1
RUN echo 'user1:qwe' | chpasswd

ENTRYPOINT service ssh restart && bash
```

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, Да извините. тут я делаю немного другое, вот сейчас изменил

Comment: `-u 0 -g 0` — это не «добавление прав». это грубая ошибка. пользователь с такими данными — администратор (обычно носит имя "root") — **уже** существует. собственно, в вашем вопросе наблюдается типичная «[ошибка молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178576)»: вы пытаетесь решить неозвученную вами проблему совершенно неправильным способом. озвучьте, пожалуйста, **действительную** проблему.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, Я пытаюсь подключиться по root правам по ssh, Но не могу подключиться с root. Пишет просто что нету доступа.

Создаю нового пользователя, и если пишу только useradd user1, то могу подключиться, но доступа на изменение файлов нету. Мне надо либо как-то решить проблему запуска с root, либо как выдать права и подключиться к этому пользователю

Comment: более правильно: изменить принадлежность тех файлов, которые вам надо исправлять. не «права», а принадлежность.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, Да я решил вопрос. Сделав права: RUN usermod -aG sudo ubuntu

Comment: Пользователь по умолчанию в контейнере root